# Problems with booting after BIOS update

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, updates, amd-ryzen

0

To begin, I have the ASRock B550M Pro4 motherboard, 3400G and a newly bought 5600x and a videocard. When I put my new 5600x in the motherboard, it didn't turn on, then I realized that I need to update my BIOS to support 5000 processors series. Okay, I went to the ASRock website and downloaded the 1.20 version of the BIOS, which introduced the support of 5000 processors series. I put my 3400g back and went to BIOS and successfully installed the new BIOS version. It restarted my PC after the update and started booting and then... Nothing happened. I restarted my PC one more time, and got the same result.

Then, I went to BIOS, checked everything and it was fine, except one thing - it stated that the version of the BIOS is 1.10, not 1.20. I tried to reinstall the 1.20 version, install previous version(1.10), install the very first version(1.00), clear CMOS, set BIOS settings to default, run Windows Troubleshooter (it said it couldn't fix the issues).

So basically I've tried everything that I found in the Internet, but it didn't help, but maybe someone here can help me with this problem?

Comment: have you tried any of the BIOS less than 3 years old?

Comment: @JaromandaX no I didn't, I've tried only the 3 versions of BIOS mentioned above. But on the newest versions there is a note that to install them "To support Ryzen 5000 series processors, it requires to update the BIOS with Matisse, Renoir or Vermeer CPU." And 3400G is a Picasso processor, so it doesn't fit those requirements.

Comment: Ahh, yes, you don't want to lock yourself out - When you update the BIOS, does it always remain at 1.10 even when flashing with 1.00? Have you tried 1.40? Have you tried the 5600X at all? Reading your question, you went back to the 3400G and never even tried the 5600X

Comment: @JaromandaX when I flash with 1.0 it displays that I have 1.0, but it doesn't boot anyway (before update it was working fine, ofc). No, I haven't tried 1.4. And no, I haven't tried 5600x since it displays that the version of the BIOS is 1.1, and it is not compatible with 5600x

Comment: Fair enough - after you flash, the BIOS is likely to have been reset. If your Windows is expecting UEFI boot (rather than CSM/BIOS boot) you may need to go into BIOS and disable CSM in the Boot page ...

Comment: @JaromandaX CSM boot was and is disabled

Comment: @Jaromandax What I think of, from 1.80 version it states To support Ryzen 5000 series processors, it requires to update the BIOS with Matisse, Renoir or Vermeer CPU. I think if it maybe also applies to 1.20 version because I have Picasso

Comment: Personally, I'd upgrade to 1.40 and take things from there

Comment: @JaromandaX I've tried upgrading to 1.40 and it didn't help. But I've found a method to update the Bios on Reddit. I installed 5600x after this and PC didn't turned on at all. CPU and dram indicators light, I tried restarting PC for two times and then it didn't turn on at all. What could it be?